# Preload game data in Objective-C with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-engine, preload

My game provides the function "Choose Level" which allow the user to select the level he wants to play (you guessed).

The way I handle this function is to load all the levels information and show them through a scrolling slideshow. The engine works fine but the problem I got is a boring "lag" (about 7 seconds) right after the "Choose Level" click. I'm sure this is about all the information the application is loading:

- All the preview images of each level (52 levels)
- Reading the PLIST file and loading data
- Calculating the completed percentage of each level by showing a progress bar

I've just created my "Loading" section but I really don't know how to handle that. Any help?

Note: I'm using SpriteKit and all the images are inside an atlas image

Answer (score 0):

First things first, try to get your load-time down by using a profiler.

As for your question:
A loading spinner would be most appropriate. You can add this to either the source view where the level is chosen or show an intermediary screen, or show the spinner on the game scene before it is ready.

I do not recommend loading the level before it is selected as this is too much work.

Comment: I have a question... If I create an intermediary screen with a loading spinner, would it block it as well? I found someone saying to perform this action via multithreading. Is it right?

Comment: You should never, ever perform your loading of resources on the main thread. No a loading spinner does not require active work and the time delay is not negligible but is minimal. My recommendation is an overlay on the game screen itself and then remove once the game screen is ready. Loading your game on main thread will slow it down. Please use grand central dispatch to make advantage of threads.